# Saving a query result into a partitioned bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to save the result of a bigquery query into a partitioned table, is that possible?  I didn't see that as an option when I tried to save.

Comment: To an existing partitioned table, or to a new table?

Comment: to a new table, I'll use the `Insert into select from` as suggested below.  I was trying to do it from the UI earlier.

Comment: this will not create partitioned table - you need to pre-create it - or use CLI - see my answer

Comment: DML will also create a table - see update :)

Comment: sure, DDL will also make a trick :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With #standardSQL and DML:

```
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table` (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT *
FROM `anothertable`
WHERE 'this is my query'
```

If the table is already partitioned by one the fields, then everything will work as expected.

If it's going to a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp)
AS
SELECT field1, field2, field3, timestamp
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE 'yourquery'
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting data into a partitioned table is the same as inserting data into a non-partitioned table. You just set destination table that is partitioned the way you need
Note, you cannot create partitioned table from query result if you are using Web UI

But you can do so using CLI for example:

bq --location=[LOCATION] query --destination_table [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] --time_partitioning_field [COLUMN] --use_legacy_sql=false '[QUERY]'